# Polkit/Consolekit is not working in openRC

Tags: polkit, openrc, consolekit, pkexec, parabola

some time ago I moved from Systemd to OpenRC. It was very different, to be able to use audio and
webcam I had to add my user to the audio, optical and video group. As some software uses pkexec to be run as
superuser, when I opened them (Because I use XFCE) nothing happened. When I used Systemd this didn´t
happened, and it´s configured to use /usr/lib/polkit-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1 (which I have
it installed). When I write pkexec in a terminal this is the output

```
$ pkexec
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is required to modify fingerprint authentication data
Authenticating as: (MY USERNAME)
Password:
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
```

I don´t know how to enable the polkit daemon/service in OpenRC, in Systemd the service it´s named "polkit". But there is ConsoleKit (what´s the difference?) which is seems to fail

```
$ service consolekit status
 * status: stopped
# service consolekit restart
 * starting consolekit . .
$ service consolekit status
 * status: crashed
```

My distro is [Parabola](https://www.parabola.nu/) (Arch Based, with the difference that is removes all the nonfree packages from the repo & Arch itself, as Arch uses Systemd, Parabola too) and I changed to OpenRC in a virtual machine, and I am testing it.

Thanks in advance

Other outputs

```
$ groups
wheel network video audio storage polkitd $USERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I dunno what packages you are using, but you probably need polkit-consolekit and maybe some others too.

Here is a guide to switch from systemd to OpenRC for Manjaro (Arch like distro):
https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=OpenRC,_an_alternative_to_systemd

Comment: I could solve my problem by using a display manager that supports consolekit (e. g. sddm-consolekit, lxdm-consolekit, mdm-nosystemd)